# Errors for respond_to do |format| in application controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, authentication

I have a helper method in my application controller and based on the request format I want to return different things. here is the method.

```
def require_facebook_sign_in!
    session[:return_to] = request.url
    unless current_user
      respond_to do |format|

        format.html {redirect_to "/auth/facebook"}
        format.json { status :created , :callback => params[:callback] }
      end

    end
  end
```

I am getting the following error. I ran a debug on it and this error is thrown for respond_to do |format|

> argumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)):
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in
>   require_facebook_sign_in!'
>
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:13:in`
>   require_facebook_sign_in!'

Why does the respond_to does not have access to format in the helper method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

i was missing a param in render json

the right way is this
format.json { render json: "errors", status: :unprocessable_entity, :callback => params[:callback]  }